# unable to get intent message on click of notification

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

Hello this problem focuses on

1. On click of notification, app should load different url in web view

Problem here I am not able to get pending intent value using .getStringExtra in MainActivity.java  I am getting null every time

**I am not an android guy so plz don't judge me if I have done any silly mistake**

Posting code for three files

1. Main_activity
2. MyNotificationManager
3. MyFireBaseMessagingServices

MainActivity

```
package com.xyz.zzz;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.attr.button;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private TextView textView;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private LinearLayout WB;
    private LinearLayout WB_ERROR;
    public String notiIntent  = "false";
    WebView webView;
    private boolean loadcheck = true;
    private String loaderror ="No Error";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WB = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.webViewLayout);
        WB_ERROR = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.webErrorLayout);
        final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",true);
        final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorMsg);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int error_code, String description , String falingUrl){
                //  webView.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/error.html");
                WB.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                WB_ERROR.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                loadcheck = false;
                loaderror = description;
                if(error_code == -8 || error_code == -6) {
                    textViewToChange.setText("Poor Internet Connectivity");
                }
                if(error_code == -14 || error_code == -2){
                    textViewToChange.setText("No Internet Connection");
                }
                /*Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is my Toast message!"+ error_code,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                if (progDailog != null && progDailog.isShowing()) {
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }

               /* Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "This is my Toast message!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("onpageload" , view);*/
                //WB.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            }

        });

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extra != null) {
            Log.d("Notification", extra.("url") + "hello Noti");
        }
        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if(intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("url") != null ) {
            Log.d("Notification", intent.getStringExtra("url"));
        }
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if(extras == null)
            {
                //Cry about not being clicked on
            }
            else if (extras.getBoolean("NotiClick"))
            {
                //Do your stuff here mate :)
            }

        }

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadUrl("example.com/index.php?" + SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getToken());
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retryButton);
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progDailog.show();
                createWebView();
                checkERROR();
            }
        });

        Log.d("sas",SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getToken());
        Log.d("Click Intent",notiIntent);
    }

    public void createWebView(){
        webView.loadUrl("example.com/index.php?" + SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getToken());
    }

    public void checkERROR(){
        if(loadcheck != false){
            WB.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            WB_ERROR.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        }
    }

    public void setNotiIntent(){
     notiIntent = "true";
        Log.d("ssssss","asas");
    }


}
```

Now MYFIREBASEMESSAGING SERVICES

```
package com.XYZ.anew;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static com.google.android.gms.internal.zzs.TAG;

/**
 * Created by AR on 16-10-2017.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCMmessageR";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be: 
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body1: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body2: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        notifyUser(remoteMessage.getFrom(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    public void notifyUser(String from , String notification){
        MyNotificationManager  myNotificationManager = new MyNotificationManager(getApplicationContext());
        myNotificationManager.showNotification(from , notification , new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Now MY NOTIFICATION MANAGER

```
package com.XYZ.anew;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

/**
 * Created by AR on 16-10-2017.
 */

public class MyNotificationManager{
    private Context ctx;




    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;
    public MyNotificationManager(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    public void showNotification(String from, String notification , Intent intent){
        MainActivity ctsx = new MainActivity();
        ctsx.setNotiIntent();
        intent.putExtra("url",true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                ctx,
                NOTIFICATION_ID,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

        Notification mNotification = builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle(from)
                .setContentText(notification)
                .setSound(uri)
                .build();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
intent.putExtra("url",true);
```

You added an "extra" with the key "url" and the value "true". This is a `boolean`. If you call `getStringExtra("url")` you will get `null`. If you call ``getBooleanExtra("url")`you will get`true`.

Also...

You absolutely positively cannot do this (in `showNotification()`):

```
    MainActivity ctsx = new MainActivity();
```

Only Android can instantiate Android components (`Service`, `Activity`, etc.).

If you need a `Context`, you need to have it passed into your method.